# Referencing a figure on the front page

Tags: biblatex, titles

I have a title page with a nice picture on it. Now I have to give the references of this picture. I am not sure how I should do this, cause I wouldn't like a [1] etc. to be on my front page next to the picture. Does anybody know how I could still include the reference in my Bibliography?
Thank you very very much!

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document`}) showing what you have tried. As it is we have to guess and I, at least, am not good at that,

Comment: I'm not sure how on topic this is for this site as its not really about TeX and friends but about how to give a citation in general. However, it isn't uncommon to see references for front covers etc. either on the next page or on the back of the book. You can do this by putting the `\cite{label}` command where you want the `[1]` to show up.

Comment: If this is a book, a descriptive reference would be appropriate in a credits or acknowledgments chapter in the back of the book.  Then it wouldn't be referenced by `\cite`, but by suitable text.

Comment: Maybe I should precise my question. Is there a way to have the reference in my bibliography without [1] somewhere in the text?

Comment: Are you looking for  `\nocite{key}`?

Comment: This appears to be a question about writing/publishing in general and not about LaTeX specifically. Once you know what you want the output to look like you can try to implement it in TeX, but the question of what the output should look like is off-topic here. If this is for an academic work you may want to ask at https://academia.stackexchange.com/. If it is about writing in general https://writing.stackexchange.com/ may be a good place to ask

Comment: `\nocite{key}` will put an item in the bibliography without putting a citation in the text. But how will the reader know that the title picture relates to the bibliography item? So you will need an acknowledgement sentence somewhere discreet, to join the two.